# Python script to create XML file works with Python 2.7.3 but not Python 2.7.9

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I wrote a Python script on my Raspberry PI 2 some time ago and now I am trying to move the script to my new PI 3. The script is generating errors on the RPI3. The only difference I can see between the RPI's is that the new one has Python 2.7.9, whereas the RPI2 had python 2.7.3!

Here is the code that works on one but not the other (note that I stripped out a lot of other code in the script to get to the basic problem).

```
import lxml.etree as ET

currenttemp = 28
root = ET.Element("root")
today_current = ET.SubElement(root, "today_current")
ET.SubElement(today_current, "currenttemp").text = str(currenttemp)
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("templates/weather.xml", method="xml", pretty_print=True)
```

**The last line generates the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    tree.write("templates/weather.xml", method="xml", pretty_print=True)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1938, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57624)
  File "serializer.pxi", line 479, in lxml.etree._tofilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:122901)
  File "serializer.pxi", line 525, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:123405)
  File "serializer.pxi", line 514, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:123246)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts on why this error is occurring?

Comment: Are you sure `templates/weather.xml` can be found from the script? Perhaps the difference is where you are running the old script from and the new script.

Comment: @davejagoda The script actually creates the file weather.xml in the templates subdirectory. In both cases, the script resides in the /home/pi/ directory and in both cases templates is a subdirectory of /home/pi/. Is the error "No such file or directory" referring to templates/weather.xml or to "lxml.etree.pyx" or the others?

Comment: I get this error if the templates directory is missing: 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2033, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63707)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 512, in lxml.etree._tofilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134950)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 571, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135614)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 560, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135415)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run this on both old and new machines to figure out if this is a problem writing `templates/weather.xml`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                     
import os
print('this is the current directory: {}'.format(os.getcwd()))
print('here are the directory contents:')
for item in os.listdir('.'):
    print(item)
```

Comment: I ran your script on both machines and at first I thought that the results were the same. However (sheepishly!!) from the output I realized that on the new machine I had created the sub directory as Templates and not templates!!! After fixing this issue my scripts run properly. Rookie mistake!!

Comment: That's great to hear! I managed to reproduce your error by accident while setting up `Python 2.7.3` and `Python 2.7.9` with `lxml`, and thus wrote the simple example above to see if that might shed some light.